# How to fix problem with fuzzy matching in helm-recentf

Tags: helm

Something changed recently with Helm and now the matching order of helm-recentf has become less useful.

For instance, in the latest version of Helm (just downloaded from Melpa) if the last visited file was `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, and in helm-recentf I type "ini", the first matched file will be `~/bin/unison` (or some other file containing "i", "n", and "i").

The logical first match should have been ~/.emacs.d/init.el, as this is the most recently visited file and it has the three letters I'm typing together.

How can I go back to the previous (and correct) behavior?  I imagine that this could be achieved by disabling fuzzy matching in helm-recentf or by changing the scoring rule.  Is there an easy way to achieve any of this?

Comment: More detail about the current behavior of helm-recentf: It seems once a key is pressed, the results are sorted according to the number of characters (e.g., `a` goes before `aa`, as the first has fewer characters).  This way of sorting discards the useful information of which file has been used more recently.  This behavior is ill-suited for helm-recentf.

Comment: This problem was solved in the new version of Helm (see comments by @Tu Do below).  Now `helm-recentf` does not do fuzzy matching by default (unless enabled by setting `helm-recentf-fuzzy-match` to `t`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answer by Helm maintainer in this [thread](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/145)

1) Fuzzy match against basename to match "ini" by either entering " -b"
after "ini" or by switching to basename with `C-]'.

2) Adding a space after "ini" to make a regexp match (fall back to
matchplugin as soon a space is detected).

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the thread.  But what I want to do is to programmatically disable fuzzy matching in helm-recentf (having to type a space or "-" or pressing C-] everytime I use this function is very un-Emacs).  Is there a simple way of disabling fuzzy matching in a helm-recentf?

Comment: Well, you can redefine [helm-source-recentf](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/eb0ec193ba3afc4cf6abbc265f7cad75f5a8ae84/helm-files.el#L2623) with `:fuzzy-match` slot removed. But if you raise an issue in the fuzzy matching thread, then the maintainer might fix it.

Comment: Done.  I posted a comment in the fuzzy matching thread.  Meanwhile I have reverted to an older version of Helm.

Comment: A new user is added: `helm-recentf-fuzzy-match` is added. You enable fuzzy match for `helm-recentf` with that variable. Now fuzzy match is off by default for `helm-recentf`. Anyway, `helm-recentf` matching is improved. Would you try it again?

Comment: Great!  I just downloaded and tested the new version (from git), and helm-recentf is working as desired.  Many thanks for the fast response!